# Angular Drawflow: How to drop component as node

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, template-strings

Is it possible to make the click event working for **template strings** like this?

```
const htmlTemplate = `
  <div>
   <div>
     <textarea df-template></textarea>
       <button (click)="test()" class="btn-submit">Add Image</button>
   </div>
  </div>
`;
```

and pass it to drawflow editor.addNode()

```
const nodeId = this.editor.addNode(
 this.selectedItem.name,
 this.selectedItem.inputs,
 this.selectedItem.outputs,
 pos_x,
 pos_y,
 'template',
 data,
 htmlTemplate,
 false
);
```

and is it possible to pass a component inside `editor.addNode()`? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No this won't work. Drawflow is not an angular specific library and won't compile the template you pass to it neither will you be able to pass a component to it.

If you want to listening to click you'll be required to use the native methods : `document.getElementById` (for example) and `addEventListener`.